# Google Maps API click eventListener is executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a Google Maps plugin for WordPress on which registered/logged in  users are able to place new markers.

In my initMap callback function I have the following function that registers when a user clicks on the map:

```
google.maps.event.addListener
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map);
});

function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
    // logged only once
    console.log('Map is clicked');

    // center clicked point on map
    map.panTo(latLng);

    // display modal box
    document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";

    // add click listener to submit button of the modal box
    document.getElementById("submit_modal").addEventListener("click", function() {

        // store values of input fields in variables
        var text_1 = document.getElementById("text_1").value;
        var text_2 = document.getElementById("text_2").value;
        var text_3 = document.getElementById("text_3").value;

        // store variables into array with the defined WordPress action
        var newPostData = {
            action: 'insert_new_post',
            some: text_1,
            added: text_2,
            data: text_3,
            location: latLng,
        };

        // logged multiple times
        console.log(newPostData);

        // pass array to a new function that processes the array using Ajax
        placeNewMarker(newPostData);
    });
}
```

As you can see the click on the map calls a new function `placeMarkerAndPanTo` that pans the clicked point to the center of the map.
After that a modal box is displayed to allow users to enter some data into three input fields. 
When the `submit_modal` button is pressed, all data of the input fields are stored into an array which is used in another function to insert a new post using Ajax.

This code works like a charm, posts are added to WordPress and markers are placed on the map.

But this process only works as intended the first time:

1. Clicking the map
2. Filling in the modal fields
3. Press the submit button of the modal

The second time this process is executed, the eventListener on my `submit_modal` is executed multiple times after one click. I've tried clearing the array and removing the click event on my `submit_modal` when it is clicked, but it didn't help.

```
newPostData = [];
document.getElementById("submit_modal").removeEventListener("click", this);
```

`console.log('Map is clicked');` is only logged once every time the map is clicked, but the contents of the `newPostData` array is logged 3 times. This also results in being added to WordPress multiple times. How can I fix my error that the `submit_modal` is only processed once?

Comment: Where did you place the `removeEventListener `?

Comment: In `document.getElementById("submit_modal").addEventListener("click", function() {});` and tested placing it above and below the call to the `placeMarker` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering same listener twice or more. For each `placeMarkerAndPanTo` call, you are registering click event listener for `submit_modal`.

You can define this listener, outside of function but if you do that you can't reach `latLng` variable. So, store `latLng` to global variable in scope of `placeMarkerAndPanTo`. And define `submit_modal` click listener outside of the function, using this global variable (or hidden input etc.).

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thank you for steering me in the right direction! I've placed the eventListener of my `submit_modal` outside the `placeMarkerAndPanTo` function, but still in my `initMap` callback. I also added a global `latLng` variable as suggested. Now everything is executed once, as desired.